# Универсальный аргумент в функции для разных адаптеров RecycleView

Tags: java, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть класс SwipeCallback, который в конструкторе принимает аргумент RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter и есть почти такой же класс RecycleViewCustomGridCardViewAdapter. И мне нужно чтобы вместо четко определенного класса в аргументы я мог передать оба класса. Как я могу это сделать? Спасибо.

*SwipeCallback*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;

public class SwipeCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private Drawable icon;
    private final ColorDrawable background;

    public SwipeCallback(RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter adapter, Context context) {
        super(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        mAdapter = adapter;
        icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.delete_trash);
        background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mAdapter.removeObject(position);
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX,
                dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int backgroundCornerOffset = 2;

        if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
            background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());

        } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
            background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        } else { // view is unSwiped
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        background.draw(c);

        int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconBottom = iconTop + icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
            int iconLeft = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin + icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int iconRight = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin;
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);

            background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());
        } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
            int iconLeft = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin - icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int iconRight = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin;
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);

            background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        } else { // view is unSwiped
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        background.draw(c);
        icon.draw(c);

    }
}
```

*Grid Adapter*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecycleViewCustomGridCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewCustomGridCardViewAdapter.UserGridViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ItemObject> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    RecycleViewCustomGridCardViewAdapter(Context context,DatabaseReference myRef, FirebaseUser user, ArrayList<ItemObject> result) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = result;
        this.myRef = myRef;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserGridViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid_card_view1, viewGroup, false);
        return new UserGridViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserGridViewHolder userViewHolder, int position) {
        final ItemObject item = mData.get(position);
        userViewHolder.Title.setText(item.getTitle());
        userViewHolder.Date.setText(item.getDate());
        userViewHolder.Time.setText(item.getTime());
        userViewHolder.Tag.setText(item.getDescription());
        userViewHolder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.add(userViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), 0, 0, "Удалить");
                menu.add(userViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), 1, 0, "Изменить");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class UserGridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView Title, Date, Time, Tag;

        public UserGridViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            Tag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    ItemObject getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    void removeObject(int position){
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(mData.get(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void updateKey( final ItemObject item1) {
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(item1.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            DatabaseReference childRef = dataSnapshot1.getRef();
                            item1.setKey(item1.getKey()-1);
                            childRef.setValue(item1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void updateDataWithKey(final ItemObject item) {
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(item.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            DatabaseReference childRef = dataSnapshot1.getRef();
                            childRef.setValue(item);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void changeObject(int position, final Activity Activity){
        ItemObject item = mData.get(position);

        openDialog(item,Activity);
    }

    private void openDialog(final ItemObject item, final Context Activity){

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Activity);
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_dialog, null);
        final EditText subEditText = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final EditText subEditTime = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        final EditText subEditDate = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        final EditText subEditTag = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        subEditText.setText(item.getTitle());
        subEditTime.setText(item.getTime());
        subEditDate.setText(item.getDate());
        subEditTag.setText(item.getDescription());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        builder.setView(subView);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        builder.setPositiveButton("Сохранить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                item.setTitle(subEditText.getText().toString());
                item.setDate(subEditDate.getText().toString());
                item.setTime(subEditTime.getText().toString());
                item.setDescription(subEditTag.getText().toString());

                updateDataWithKey(item);

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity, "Отменено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

*List Adapter*

```
package com.example.p1ng2win.onlinehelper4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter.UserListViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private ArrayList<ItemObject> result;

    RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter(Context context,DatabaseReference myRef, FirebaseUser user, ArrayList<ItemObject> result) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.myRef = myRef;
        this.user = user;
        this.result = result;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_card_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter.UserListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserListViewHolder userListViewHolder, int position) {
        final ItemObject item = result.get(position);
        userListViewHolder.Text.setText(item.getTitle());
        userListViewHolder.Date.setText(item.getDate());
        userListViewHolder.Time.setText(item.getTime());
        userListViewHolder.Description.setText(item.getDescription());
        userListViewHolder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.add(userListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), 0, 0, "Удалить");
                menu.add(userListViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), 1, 0, "Изменить");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return result.size();
    }

    public class UserListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView Text, Date, Time, Description;

        public UserListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            Description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    ItemObject getItem(int id) {
        return result.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener (ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener =  itemClickListener;
    }

    void removeObject(int position){
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(result.get(position).getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void updateKey( final ItemObject item1) {
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(item1.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            DatabaseReference childRef = dataSnapshot1.getRef();
                            item1.setKey(item1.getKey()-1);
                            childRef.setValue(item1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void updateDataWithKey(final ItemObject item) {
        myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("tasks").orderByChild("key").equalTo(item.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            DatabaseReference childRef = dataSnapshot1.getRef();
                            childRef.setValue(item);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    void changeObject(int position, final Activity Activity){
        ItemObject item = result.get(position);

        openDialog(item,Activity);
    }

    private void openDialog(final ItemObject item, final Context Activity){

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Activity);
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_dialog, null);
        final EditText subEditText = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final EditText subEditTime = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        final EditText subEditDate = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        final EditText subEditDescription = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        subEditText.setText(item.getTitle());
        subEditTime.setText(item.getTime());
        subEditDate.setText(item.getDate());
        subEditDescription.setText(item.getDescription());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        builder.setView(subView);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        builder.setPositiveButton("Сохранить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                item.setTitle(subEditText.getText().toString());
                item.setDate(subEditDate.getText().toString());
                item.setTime(subEditTime.getText().toString());
                item.setDescription(subEditDescription.getText().toString());

                updateDataWithKey(item);

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity, "Отменено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

объект `RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter` фигурирует в трех местах класса `SwipeCallback`:

- описании полей класса `private RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter mAdapter;`
- параметрах конструктора `RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter adapter`
- теле конструктора `mAdapter = adapter;`
- единственный раз в методах класса `mAdapter.removeObject(position);`

Последняя строчка является ключевой, т.к. именно она определяет что мы делаем с получаемым объектом. Значит нас устроит любой объект, у которого можно вызвать `.removeObject(position)`
Как это сделать?

Сначала посмотреть на код классов, которые мы хотим использовать. В обоих классах есть одноименный метод `void removeObject(int position)`. Значит мы можем ожидать от объектов этих классов схожего поведения. Дело за малым, изменить `SwipeCallback` так, чтобы он мог работать с любым объектом, реализующим это поведение. Тут нам понадобится интерфейс:

```
public interface ObjectRemovable {
    void removeObject(int position);
}
```

Вот и все. Интерфейс нам говорит что у объекта любого класса, реализующего данный интерфейс можно вызвать `void removeObject(int position)`.

Заменяем в `SwipeCallback` класс `RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter` на наш интерфейс:

```
private ObjectRemovable mAdapter;
ObjectRemovable adapter;
```

Теперь в `SwipeCallback` можно передавать любой объект, принадлежащий классу с  методом `void removeObject(int position)`. Почти.

Если бы это был Golang с [дактайпингом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), то на это можно было бы и закончить. В Java нужно явно указать какие классы реализуют данный интерфейс.

```
public class RecycleViewCustomListCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<...что то там ...> implements ObjectRemovable {...
public class RecycleViewCustomGridCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<...что то там ...> implements ObjectRemovable {
```

Вот сейчас оба класса явно реализуют интерфейс `ObjectRemovable` и все должно работать.

Answer (score 2):

Оба класса должны реализовывать (implements) общий интерфейс, 
и принимающий метод должен принимать данные с типом этого интерфейса

```
public void yourMethod (YourInterface var) {
...
}
```

Comment: Те мне нужно сделать им одинаковый user view holder?

Comment: Для организации своих классов ты можешь попробовать просто нарисовать схемку из квадратиков...  так вот, чтобы твой принимающий метод мог обрабатывать разные классы, эти классы все же должны обладать чем-то общим и имя этому общему - интерфейс. Как ты назовешь свой интерфейс, это уже у твое дело. Просто пойми сам принцип. Интерфейс это не хранитель данных. Это маркер который четко сообщает - у всех классов, которые меня реализуют, есть вот-эти методы. И соответственно с ними всеми можно работать одинаково.